# ActionController::RoutingError No route matches [POST] for remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok

So I'm trying to allow a user to record and stop recording a session that they are in.

My routes:

```
resources :archives
post 'stop_recording' => 'archives#stop_recording', as: :stop_recording
```

my archives_controller:

```
def create
  @room = Room.find_by(guid: params[:guid])
  archive = OPENTOK.archives.create @room.session_id
  @room.archives.create(archive_token: archive.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def stop_recording
  @room = Room.find_by(guid: params[:guid])
  @archive = Archive.find_by(room_id: @room.id)
  OPENTOK.archives.stop_by_id @archive.archive_token
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and my js:

for stop_recording.js.erb:

```
$("#record_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('rooms/partials/start_recording')) %>");
```

for create.js.erb:

```
$("#record_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('rooms/partials/stop_recording')) %>");
```

and my partials:

```
<%= form_for @room.archives.build, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :guid, @room.guid %>
  <%= f.button do %>
    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for stop_recording_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.button do %>
    End Recording
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

now doing a create works fine, the issue is when I wish to stop_recording that I get the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/rooms/elnlo4"
```

which is the room the session is being held in.

rake routes output:

```
                 PATCH    /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                 PUT      /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                 DELETE   /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#destroy
          charge POST     /charge/:room_id(.:format)                  transactions#create
         surveys POST     /surveys(.:format)                          surveys#create
        archives POST     /archives(.:format)                         archives#create
  stop_recording POST     /stop_recording(.:format)                   archives#stop_recording
           rooms GET      /rooms(.:format)                            rooms#index
                 POST     /rooms(.:format)                            rooms#create
        new_room GET      /rooms/new(.:format)                        rooms#new
    room_receipt GET      /rooms/:guid/receipt(.:format)              rooms#receipt
            room GET      /rooms/:guid(.:format)                      rooms#show
     room_finish GET      /rooms/:guid/session_ended(.:format)    

    rooms#finish
  customer_heartbeat POST     /customers/:customer_id/heartbeat(.:format) customers#heartbeat
      customer_start POST     /customers/:customer_id/start(.:format)     customers#start
           customers POST     /customers(.:format)                        customers#create
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your config/routes.rb?

Comment: i did, they're on top! :)

Comment: whoops missed it sorry.

Comment: Add the output of `rake routes`

Comment: Really makes no sense that `stop_recording_path` is generating that `"/rooms/elnlo4"` path. Sorry.

Comment: FYI, I haven't given on your issue but I have to readdress when I get more time. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your stop_recording partial with:

```
<%= form_tag stop_recording_path, :method => :post, remote: true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :guid, @room.guid %>
  <%= button_tag do %>
    End Recording
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```